# Filter dataframe by multiple criteria in Python (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

I am having a problem filtering my dataframe by multiple criteria. I have no problem filtering by one criteria (string).

I have an excel sheet with around 15 columns. First, I filtered my dataframe by specific column, let's say by column2, column4, column5, and column11, by using the following code:

```
df_name_filtered_columns = df_srm[["column2","column4","column5","column11"]]
```

Then, I need to filter further this dataframe.

- column2 contains specific cities and I want it to show only 2 of them
- column5 contains jobs and I want to show only 2 jobs also
- column11 contiants some float numbers, and I want it to show only ones greater than 0.

I tried to apply these filters with the following code, but it doesn't work.

```
df_srm_final = df_name_filtered_columns[df_name_filtered_columns["column2"].srt.contains("city1") |
                                          df_name_filtered_columns["column2"].srt.contains("city4") |
                                          df_name_filtered_columns["column5"].srt.contains("job3") |
                                          df_name_filtered_columns["column5"].srt.contains("job9") |
                                          df_name_filtered_columns["column11"] > 0]
```

How can I obtain my result?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the and and or conditions wisely. Here you can use something like the following

```
df_srm_final = df_name_filtered_columns[(((df_name_filtered_columns["column2"] == "city1") |
                                          (df_name_filtered_columns["column2"] == "city4") ) 
                                         &
                                          ((df_name_filtered_columns["column5"] == "job3") |
                                           (df_name_filtered_columns["column5"] == "job9") )
                                         &
                                          (df_name_filtered_columns["column11"] > 0))]
```